# Erro ao passar informação de uma linha do datagrid de um form para o datagrid de outro form

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Estou com um seguinte erro ao passar informação da linha selecionada de uma grid do form1 para a grid do form2

Segue o código da grid do Form1

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (Int32 index = 0; index < dgw_separacaopic.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            if (bool.Parse(dgw_separacaopic.Rows[index].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()) == true)
            {
                frmSepfatpic sep = new frmSepfatpic();
                sep.Pedido = dgw_separacaopic.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                sep.Show();

            }

        }
```

Segue o código das grid do form2 que esta recebendo o valor

```
 public partial class frmSepfatpic : Form
{
    public string Pedido { get; set; }
    //public string Item { get; set; }
    //public string Cliente { get; set; }
    //public string QTDA { get; set; }
    public frmSepfatpic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmSepfatpic_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgw_sepfatpic.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = Pedido;
    }
}
```

Imagem do erro no form2
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece por que você está tentando acessar uma linha que ainda não existe, tente fazer desta forma:

```
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add("collumName", "HeaderText");
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add("collumName1", "HeaderText1");

 string[] row1 = new string[] { "column2 value", "column6 value" };
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
```

Comment: Lodi obrigado pela ajuda, mas agora esta apresentando um erro que o índice da coluna não pode ser negativo..

Comment: Informações adicionais: O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.Nessa linha dgw_sepfatpic.Columns[1].Name = "PEDIDO";

Comment: "O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.\r\nNome do parâmetro: index"}

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta, você deve adicionar a coluna antes de adicionar a nova linha. faça um teste, se funcionar não esqueça de marcar como resposta e dar um upvote...

Comment: Perfeito Lodi obrigado.